# touch sensor for metal door handle

Tags: integrated-circuit, circuit-design, current-measurement, voltage-measurement, detection

I was thinking if a current is applied to a metal door handled and somebody touched it that should complete the circuit to ground and be detectable but I'm not sure if this would work as the 'somebody' most likely will be wearing rubber soles and even a rubber glove. But if it was sensitive enough it might work?

Can anybody suggest a circuit maybe using current as I mentioned or capitance (increasing the capacitance by touching the handle made part of capacitor) or inductance (deviative a coil by touching the handle made part of an inductor)?

Or something else that is triggered by touching the metal handle?

Comment: It depends on the purpose of the switch. https://nl.aliexpress.com/i/32830267123.html?spm=a2g0z.12057483.0.0.b08e167e33rbTk

Answer (score 1):

A darlington pair with its base connected to the handle or a MOSFET with its gate connected to the handle (and 15MΩ to Vdd) will do the trick.

If you want the MOSFET variant in a more modern and more reliable fashion, use a **capacitive touch switch** IC as e.g. the IQS228 or a pure software solution on a µC. This method has the advantage it also works through coatings. Door handles are usually coated with clear paint finish.

Comment: I'm not sure if the IQS228  or TTP223 Touch button Module will work without a its dedicated touch pad? maybe the handle can be used According to the application note https://www.elecrow.com/download/TTP223_SPEC.pdf  The range of Cs value is 0~50pF. I will also try the MOSFET with its gate connected to the handle (and 15MΩ to Vdd).

Comment: according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_capacitance it is 100pF

Comment: To my practical knowlegde, it also depends on interferences from fluorescent lights etc. if you can get a stable result. You have to try it at the very spot you want to install it.

Answer (score 0):

You should do some research into touch sensors and touch sensor circuits. There are even some microcontroller manufacturers that are offering touch sensing application notes and some even include the touch sensor circuitry right on the MCU.

You want to concentrate on capacitive touch sensor technology as it does not depend upon a direct current path through the human body. Instead it depends upon the capacitive change in the circuit when a human touches the sensor.

If the circuit is configured correctly you may very well get your metal door knob to work as a touch sensor. It would likely not work so well if the knob is mounted in a metal or metal clad door.

Comment: TTP223 are very cheap but how to make the handle into a toach sensor is not clear; it is mounted on a plactic door. According to the application note https://www.elecrow.com/download/TTP223_SPEC.pdf  The range of Cs value is 0~50pF according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_capacitance it is 100pf

Comment: @onepound - Have you done any experimentation to try connecting the door knob to the touch sensor?

Comment: no - but based on the suggestions so far I will order one and try but first  I'll try that mosfet suggestion though I do not think it will work.